# Why doesn't this PDO prepared statement work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For the life of me I cannot seem to get this simple insert query to work:

```
try {

// Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

// Create an array of all data to be inserted
$data = array(':id'      => 'null',
              ':name'       => $name,
              ':location'   => $loc,
              ':latitude'   => $lat,
              ':longitude'  => $lon,
              ':website'    => $web,
              ':bandcamp'   => $bandcamp,
              ':facebook'   => $facebook,
              ':bio'        => $bio,
              ':image'      => $image,
              ':updated'    => 'null');

// Create sql statement
$sql = 'INSERT INTO artists VALUES (:id, :name, :location, :latitude, :longitude, :website, :bandcamp, :facebook, :bio, :image, :updated)';

// Run query
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($data);

// Disconnect from database
$dbh = null;

}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The data is not being inserted into the table and I am not getting any error messages.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: It looks syntactically valid.  You're going to have to do some debugging.  In particular, the default error mode of PDO is to handle errors silently.  You must set it to throw exceptions.  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Many thanks.  Turns out that one of the variables was set to `null`, thus causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute those PDO methods, you should check that they didn't return `false`, and handle if so, to know if and where your code is failing.

Also, it looks like you are inserting the string value `'null'` into your `id` and `updated` fields. That could be causing a problem (see the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for that). And make sure any fields that you are *not* inserting are okay to be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
':id'      => 'null',
```

might not work if your table has that as primary key and auto increment